# Summing a set of values based on cell content and row position

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In the below table rows 2,3 and 4 have some details of a sporting event.
Range A2:C4 has a set of squad numbers and range D2:F4 has the details of who scored goals.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   Squad #     Scorers     
2   1   3   6   2   8   3
3   3   6   7   6   1   
4   1   5   6   7   2   4
```

As an example squad # 6 has scored 8 goals based on the values equivalent position in the Squad section and relative to the Scorers range.
What formula will give me this total value and the equivalent total values for all squad numbers like the table below?
Some cells will be empty like F3.

```
1   9                   
3   14                  
5   2                   
6   8                   
7   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) should take care of this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($D$2:$F$4, --($A$2:$C$4=H2))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: sumproduct_scorers]

Answer (score 0):

With only 3 games, the simplest way that I can see to do this would be to use 4 SUMIFS statements, as follows [assumes that your results data is in columns A & B, starting at row 5 and moving down; A5:A12 would hold the IDs for the different squads, and this formula would go in B5 and be copied down]:

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$F$2,$A$2:$C$2,A5)+SUMIFS($D$3:$F$3,$A$3:$C$3,A5)+SUMIFS($D$4:$F$4,$A$4:$C$4,A5)
```

What it does is sum columns D:F, for row 1, row 2, and row 3, based on the fact that columns A:C for those rows match the appropriate squad ID.

This would be possible with an arguably shorter but more complex Array Formula, but with the data as you've presented it, I feel this is the clearest method.

Comment: this is just a small sample and the current amount of squad numbers is 34 and this will grow. Plus there are eight squad number positions and eight equivalent goal scoring positions. Sorry maybe should have said this up front